# Xamarin MR.Gestures move ContentView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I am trying to use MR.Gestures to move my ContentView, so I tried this:

```
var draggableView = new MR.Gestures.ContentView { VerticalOptions = 

LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand };
draggableView.Panning += (dd, ee) => 
{
    if(ee.Touches != null)
    {
        if (ee.Touches.Length == 1)
        {
            draggableView.TranslationX = ee.Touches[0].X;
            draggableView.TranslationY = ee.Touches[0].Y;
        }
    }
};
```

But that doesn't move the ContentView at all. The 2 lines which need to translate are never reached so `ee.Touches` is always `null`...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are assuming that e.Touches is not null

Comment: Yeah, because the event gets triggered if you are planning, which means there must be at least 1 touch?

Comment: I have no idea.  But you should always test for null before accessing an objects properties

Comment: Can you share the rest of your code? Are you sure you are using it the right way? https://github.com/Knight1988/Xamarin.Form.MultiLevelListView/blob/e0998a082b5417e07c6fd772bea9677304eb32fe/TestApp/TestApp/Pages/MrGestureMultiLevelListViewPage.cs

Comment: This is the only code where I use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is the only code where I use it

Maybe you forget to set the `contentview` to Content. And for better perform, I set the background color.

You also need to change the value of `TranslationX` and `TranslationY`. It will make the contentvew moved smoothly.

**Change:**

```
                    draggableView.TranslationX = ee.Touches[0].X;
                    draggableView.TranslationY = ee.Touches[0].Y;
```

**To:**

```
                    draggableView.TranslationX += ee.DeltaDistance.X;
                    draggableView.TranslationY += ee.DeltaDistance.Y;
```

You could try the code below.

```
var draggableView = new MR.Gestures.ContentView
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            BackgroundColor = Color.Accent
        };

       Content = draggableView;

        draggableView.Panning += (dd, ee) =>
        {
            if (ee.Touches != null)
            {
                if (ee.Touches.Length == 1)
                {
                    //draggableView.TranslationX = ee.Touches[0].X;
                    //draggableView.TranslationY = ee.Touches[0].Y;
                    draggableView.TranslationX += ee.DeltaDistance.X;
                    draggableView.TranslationY += ee.DeltaDistance.Y;
                }
            }
        };
```

**Result:**

[image]